# What are the steps required to mount the external storage (SD card) of Samsung Galaxy S from a chroot shell

Tags: android, ubuntu, mount, smartphone

I have placed an ubuntu.img file in a folder on my SD card as well as the following scripts obtained from - http://blog.coralic.nl/2010/08/17/ubuntu-on-samsung-galaxy-s-android/

> /mnt/sdcard/ubuntu/start

```
#!/bin/bash
#Created by Armin Coralic http://blog.coralic.nl
if [ "$1" == "" ] ; 
then
    echo "You need to specify the img file!"
    exit 9;
fi

if `test -d /data/local/mnt` ; then
   echo "/data/local/mnt"
else
   mkdir /data/local/mnt
fi

export HOME=/root
export USER=root
export PATH=$bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:$PATH

mount -o loop,noatime -t ext2 $1 /data/local/mnt
sleep 3
mount -t proc proc /data/local/mnt/proc
mount -t devpts devpts /data/local/mnt/dev/pts
chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/bash
```

> /mnt/sdcard/ubuntu/stop

```
#!/bin/bash
#Created by Armin Coralic http://blog.coralic.nl

umount /data/local/mnt/dev/pts
umount /data/local/mnt/proc 
umount /data/local/mnt
```

After running the *start* script, I get an ubuntu chrooted shell, but I do not have access to my external storage SD card from within the chroot.

I would like to know the answer for the following two questions:

> - 1) what is the /dev/block/ device file name for the external SD card
>     which I should mount on a Samsung
>     Galaxy S I9000?
> - 2) what is the exact syntax that I should use before/after entering
>     chroot to get read/write/execute
>     access to the external SD storage?

It would be helpful if the start/stop scripts could be modified with the required changes.

Comment: Running the following:
_mount -o bind /dev/block/vold/179:9 /sdcard/ubuntu/extsd_

Returns the following error:
_mount: /dev/block/vold/179: Unknown host_
_mount: mounting /dev/block/vold/179:9 on /sdcard/ubuntu/extsd failed: Connection refused_

Any idea why?

Comment: seems to be a result of CMW MOD - restoring to backed up stock ROM gives a different error:
_mount: /dev/block/vold/179: Unknown server error_
_mount: mounting /dev/block/vold/179:9 on /sdcard/ubuntu/extsd failed: No such file or directory_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the block devices by running ls in /dev/block/ 
But actually, there are multiple ways to address the devices, for instance through vold, or sys etc.

you might check a file cald vold.fstab, it should give you an idea of which device is your external SD car